# unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE) while output

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm sorry if my question may appear silly, but I'm really confused with an error I'm getting while outputting a file name from array.

First I'm populating array with a column names from my database. Here is the code:

```
    $AddNews = "SELECT * FROM picture_names";
$result = mysql_query( $AddNews, $IVE_Connection ) or die('ERROR: '.mysql_error());
for($i = 0; $i < mysql_num_fields($result); $i++){
    $field_info = mysql_fetch_field($result, $i);
    $name_array[] = $field_info->name;
}

    for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($name_array); $i++){
    echo "<input type='file' name='".$name_array[$i]."'    id='".$name_array[$i]."' value=''>";
    echo "</span><br />";
    echo "</div>";
}
```

There is no problem in that stage. But when I'm trying. I can Output in normally. The problem starts when i try to print condition with the same array:

```
for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($name_array); $i++){
echo "if($_FILES['".$name_array[$i]."']['tmp_name'] != ''){";// the problem ocures here
   ...some code here
echo "}";
}
```

here I always have a mistake `unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE)` Itried to stringify it but still having the same error. if I output just an array outside of `$_FILES` logic there is no problem.

I would be grateful if someone can point me what am I doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($name_array); $i++){

  if(isset($_FILES[$name_array[$i]]['tmp_name'])){
      //your code
  }
}
```

Comment: Does it check if the file is not empty? because this is what I want to fish out

Comment: yes if the process will be performed only to those file pickers which were used

Comment: it actually worked. i made it this way `echo "if(".$_FILES[$name_array[$i]]['tmp_name']." != ''){";`

Answer (score 0):

This is not the correct code:

```
for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($name_array); $i++){
echo "if($_FILES['".$name_array[$i]."']['tmp_name'] != ''){";// the problem ocures here
   ...some code here
echo "}";
}
```

Just remove the echo form the code

```
for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($name_array); $i++){
  if($_FILES[$name_array[$i]]['tmp_name'] != ''){
     echo "Text";
  };
}
```